# Let $\{x_n\}_{n \in\mathbb{N}}$ be a bounded sequence of real numbers. Let us define $y_n = \sup\{x_k : k \geq n\}$ and $z_n = \inf{x_k : k \geq n}.$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, supremum-and-infimum, limsup-and-liminf

Let $\{x_n\}_{n \in\mathbb{N}}$ be a bounded sequence of real numbers. Let us define, for each ${n \in\mathbb{N}},$
$$y_n = \sup\{x_k : k \geq n\}$$ and $$z_n = \inf\{x_k : k \geq n\}.$$

Prove that the sequence $\{x_n\}_{n \in\mathbb{N}}$ is convergent if and only if $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} y_n = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} z_n$.

Answer (score 0):

First to all $z_n\leq x_n\leq y_n$ for every $n\in\mathbb N$. So if $\lim_{n\to +\infty}z_n=\lim_{n\to +\infty}y_n$ by squeeze theorem also $x_n$ is convergent.

Conversely if $\lim_{n\to +\infty}x_n=x\in\mathbb R$ for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $N\in\mathbb N$ so that $x-\varepsilon\leq x_n\leq x+\varepsilon$ for every $N\in\mathbb N$. For every $N'>N$ we have so
$$
x-\varepsilon \leq z_{N'}\leq x_n\leq y_{N'}\leq x+\varepsilon
$$
for every $n\geq N'$, in other words $\lim_{n\to +\infty}y_n=\lim_{n\to +\infty}z_n=x$.